# Apache Arrow table.concat doesn't unify batch dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, apache-arrow, arrowjs

I am periodically updating an arrow table with additional arrow data.
The arrow data is retrieved from the same source, so same schema.
I am creating a fresh table from the incoming buffer with some client side
column additions, and then concatenating the new table onto the primary table using the arrow defined concat function.

This works fantastic, until I use the countBy method - which looks to only
use the last batch dictionary which comes from the most recent poll. This
dictionary might account for 1% of the data in the table, and thus is
definitely not a delta.

A significant portion of our application code relies upon dictionary deltas. Is there any way to unify the dictionaries, or am I sunk into converting the concatted table into json and back into an arrow table to get back to the last batch dictionary being the most relevant to the whole table? This would completely kill performance unfortunately.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this the same question as https://lists.apache.org/thread/hfo6mpvxvvp6n0o24mdj9q5jycq1j8nm? If you don't get a good answer there or here, filing an issue and tagging one of the JS maintainers might be good.